# increase Xorg mouse framerate

Tags: mouse

I am happy with my mouse speed, acceleration etc, but I would like to increase the frame rate of mouse pointer, in other words the time between redraws. I noticed that if I just move the mouse around it is drawn infrequently and it basically move about an inch or two between redraws. I just played a linux opengl game and the mouse movement in the game had a very good frame rate, mouse felt super smooth. Back to desktop it feels like 5 fps or something.

Please do not suggest changing acceleration, speed, mouse transformation matrix etc, those are fine. All I am asking is is this even possible and how to draw my mouse more frequent, maybe 30 fps or 60 fps. I am on a very fast modern PC for God's sake, can it draw a 32 pixel wide mouse icon at 60 fps and not 5?

Comment: Xorg mouse framerate ??? There 's something I just cannot understand in that. A/ locate the IRQ associated to the usb host controller your mouse is attached to. (kinfocenter if running KDE/Plasma or equiv.) B/ Monitor the interrupt rate (ksysguard if running KDE/plasma or equivalent) keep moving the mouse and tell us about the interrupt rate. (around 120/s would be standard)

Comment: @MC68020 I don't think this is about USB polling, because in games mouse is smooth. Its something about how X draws a mouse. It's 5 times a second at maximum.

Comment: Basically all modern graphic cards use hardware support to draw the mouse pointer, which means it will be drawn each frame at the current position, at the maximum framerate possible. Whatever it is that makes you think you have a "low frame rate" must be something else (unless you have old or misconfigured hardware, check the Xorg.log).

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse is smooth when you drag a window I suggest you to look in the direction of adaptive frame rate.

Xorg must be configured in some eco configuration that lower frame rate when no extra resources are needed.

In this case I suggest you to fix your frame rate.